# How can I fix the tiny type in iOS 10 Mail?

Tags: mail.app, bug, accessibility, ios

The update to iOS 10 has made type in Mail messages often appear too tiny to read. How do I restore readable type in iOS 10 Mail?

---

This is *not* a question about how to globally adjust text size (the text is fine elsewhere) or about how to zoom (that really doesn't fix the problem), but about how to make text that appears unreadably small some mail messages appear as it did in iOS 9.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem here. Does it happen with all senders or only with some? Does it also happen if you send a mail to yourself?

Comment: It happens with about half of the mail I receive. I think it only happens with formatted mail (including HTML mail I send to myself); plain text mail is unaffected (as near as I can tell). Everyone I know has the same issue.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what is being asked for. Can the issue be resolved by choosing Settings (cmd+,) --> Fonts & Colours, and changing the fonts there?

Comment: @nataliaeire: No. The point is to avoid changing fonts globally with are fine. The issue only occurs with (many but not all) HTML e-mails. It seems something changed with the HTML renderer in Mail and the result is that common markup results in minuscule text. It's probably something only Apple can fix.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Again—because I heard this specific issue being discussed on a recent podcast involving HTML text rendering in iOS 10, I am curious to know if the "fix" that worked for the podcaster works for you: Can you force quit Mail and see if the same messages render properly at least for a time?

Comment: I'm seeing an issue with my company's HTML emails that affects iPhone 5 sized screens (so 5, 5s, & 6SE). The content only uses about 75% of the width of the screen. I haven't found a fix yet. Does this sound like your issue?

Comment: @SeanMahan: No. What I see is that the text for some mails (HTML only as near as I can tell, but not all HTML mail) is minuscule, but it still wraps the full width of the screen.

Comment: I can confirm this is an issue. I'm still having it. New iPhone 7. Occasionally, messages will load with very tiny text. Quitting the app and reopening does produce larger text, but the problem returns. There is no perceivable pattern for when or why the problem occurs. As far as further background info, Gmail is my main Mail account and I've experienced problems in the past between Mail.app and Gmail; I've wondered if this is one of those times.

Comment: I think I have the same issue; for me it's consistently with NYTimes daily emails, which are HTML formatted and _almost_ too small to read.  Restarting Mail has no effect.  I think what's wanted is to set the minimum type display size someplace.

Answer (score 2):

Try force quitting mail (double click the home button on your device to enter the task switcher and swipe the card for mail upwards). Then re-launch mail to see if the text is appropriately sized.

Comment: That's not how you force-quit.

Comment: Beg your pardon but Apple disgrees with you. 
Here’s how to force an app to close:
View your open apps. 

Double-click the Home button to see your most recently used apps.


Find the app to close

Swipe right or left to find the app that you want to close.        


Swipe up to close

Swipe up on the app's preview to close the app.      


from https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201330

Comment: Or was it the word "tap" you objected to? If so, it's better practice to make a specific recommendation or edit to the answer if the process is essentially correct.

Comment: And in any case, does force quitting have an effect? John Gruber mentioned this issue with iOS 10 and Mail on Ep 167 of his podcast The Talk Show

Comment: That's "forcing an app to close", which is not the same as [Force Quitting](https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/how-to-force-quit-ios-app/).

Comment: Is there anywhere that it's documented that those are not the same? I can't even find an acknowledgment from Apple that method exists though obviously it does.

Comment: Does *either* method solve the problem of small text in certain messages?

Comment: [Yes, here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html). The critical difference is that an app that's not the focus will should have executed any and all termination code already, while an app that's actually Force Quit will not have any such opportunity. That's why just quitting normally can't have any effect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45716/discussion-between-samh-and-raxacoricofallapatorius).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the process I just used that I read on [Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7667124?start=0&tstart=0):

1. In Mail settings, turn off "Complete Threads"
2. Close the Mail app (double click home button, swipe Mail app up)
3. Open the Mail app from home screen
4. In Mail settings, re-enable "Complete Threads"

---

(So far this solution is working, but even just closing and re-opening the app works for a time. I will update this answer with information on if this was a permanent fix or not.)

Answer (score 0):

This has been a persistent and annoying problem for me. But I just discovered that enabling *all* of the threading options in Mail version 11.2.2 seems to fix the problem, and turning the options off seems to bring it back.

I wish Apple would fix this right.

[image]